# how to return couple of variables in models.py

Tags: python, django

i need to return shop_nama nad adress to django site administration, here's the code

```
    shop_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    adress = models.TextField(max_length=264, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shop_name
```

but it shows error when i type
`return self.shop_name, self.adress`
error says: **str** returned non-string (type tuple)

sooo how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use F String in str function:

```
 def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.shop_name},{self.adress }"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can return only one string to the administration page in Django, which is the string you will read on it.

You need to concatanate strings

```
shop_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
adress = models.TextField(max_length=264, default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.shop_name + ' ' + self.adress
```

(Assuming that `self.adress` is a string)